# How to convert Kobold2D into a new Cocos2D 3.x project?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6, kobold2d

I love Kobold2D, but since the upgrades of Xcode and it seems the Kobold2D has been discontinued (may be kobold touch is still updating, I'm not sure), which I can not even run it on Xcode 6. I am forcing to change my project from Kobold2D to Cocos2D, which a lots might change.

I wonder, instead manually create a new one and copy paste every bits of my code and change them, is there a quick shot for making a Kobold2D into Cocos2d? (e.g replace libraries, change configs, etc)

For the project, I am using the basic cocos2D functions, with TiledMap, particle Designer, Texture packer and some more basic Kobold2D functions.

Thank you

Comment: There's no quick shot, just lots of manual labor. Cocos2d v2 and v3 in themselves are rather different, if you used Kobold2D features on top you may need to adapt or port those too (for instance Lua integration).

Answer (score 0):

You can roll back to Xcode 5.1.1 and Kobold2d projects will run again.