# How to update Kobold2D 2.1 project to MacOS10.10 / XCode 6.1?

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

we've got a major project written in Kobold2D by Steffen Itterheim, (which is itself a wrapper for Cocos 2.1), and since upgrading to XCode 6.1/OS X 10.10, the new iOS 8 framework seems to render many parts of the Kobold-library and the Cocos implementation unusable, or it seems to need a rewrite.

- Has anyone updated a Kobold2D project successfully to iOS8 yet?
- Are there simple ways to upgrade it, or is it necessary to rewrite the entire library?
- If there are no simple ways to upgrade, has anyone migrated a project from Kobold to cocos 3 yet?

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Averett

PS. I have seen this question: [How to convert Kobold2D into a new Cocos2D 3.x project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995174/how-to-convert-kobold2d-into-a-new-cocos2d-3-x-project) - but the answer is not very helpful, as this solution would omit iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually have created a script to make the necessary changes to Kobold2D. You can find it in this post:
https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/406/xcode-6-fixes-for-kobold2d

Basically all you need to do is run

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/mgwu-misc/xcode6_kobold_patch.sh | sh
```

in the terminal, when you are in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks Ben-G -- this looks fantastic - alas, I'm getting a linker error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "___isnan", referenced from:
      -[OALGainAction prepareWithTarget:] in libobjectal-ios.a(OALAudioActions.o)
      -[OALPitchAction prepareWithTarget:] in libobjectal-ios.a(OALAudioActions.o)
      -[OALPanAction prepareWithTarget:] in libobjectal-ios.a(OALAudioActions.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any ideas?

Comment: NOTE: Ben-G`s fix does not work for the OAL library in Kobold. TO fix that, check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917172/how-to-fix-oalaudio-library-for-xcode-6-kobold2d-linker-error

Answer (score 1):

I have just compiled my Kobold2D 2.1 project using XCode 6.0.1. It breaks initially at several lines, but it's easy to fix. I only found a couple of errors:

1. Multiple methods named 'setPosition:' found
   **Example**:
   [_target setPosition: newPos];

   **Fix:** cast the object to CCNode
   [(CCNode*)_target setPosition: newPos];

   Do this for all errors found

You also need to import "ccNode.h" at the top of the file.

2. Use of undeclared identifier 'MPMovieControlModeHidden'
   I found that the #ifdef__ #endif enclosing the offending line was commented out. Uncomment them to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks David I'll give this a shot - if so, yours will be marked as the correct answer :-D