# How to fix OALAudio Library for XCode 6 / Kobold2D (Linker Error)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, linker, kobold2d

trying to update a Kobold2D/Cocos2d 2.1 project for iOS 8.1/XCode 6 on Yosemite.

After using the solution provided here ([How to update Kobold2D 2.1 project to MacOS10.10 / XCode 6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591350/how-to-update-kobold2d-2-1-project-to-macos10-10-xcode-6-1)), I get a linker error that, despite all attempts (restarting, cleaning, deleting and adding frameworks) persists, and makes my project unstartable.
I'm at my wit's end; this is a 3 year project, and I'm hitting a brick wall... The XCode 6.1 linker error reads as such:

```
Ld /Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OME.app/OME normal i386
    cd /Users/fabian/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.1.0/OME
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Intermediates/OME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OME-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/OME.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lz -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenGLES -force_load /Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libkobold2d-ios.a -force_load /Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-ios.a -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GameKit -weak_framework iAd -weak_framework MessageUI -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework UIKit -weak-lSystem -lstdc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreFoundation -framework GameKit -lbox2d-ios -lchipmunk-ios -lchipmunk-spacemanager-ios -lcocos2d-extensions-ios -lcocos2d-ios -lcocos3d-ios -lcocosdenshion-ios -lkobold2d-ios -lobjectal-ios -lsneakyinput-ios -lwax-ios -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Intermediates/OME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OME-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/OME_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/fabian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OME-abspfkzbpimdpqaoclhujzvtfred/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OME.app/OME

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "___isnan", referenced from:
      -[OALGainAction prepareWithTarget:] in libobjectal-ios.a(OALAudioActions.o)
      -[OALPitchAction prepareWithTarget:] in libobjectal-ios.a(OALAudioActions.o)
      -[OALPanAction prepareWithTarget:] in libobjectal-ios.a(OALAudioActions.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

PLEASE pretty please: Does anybody have an idea? I might not understand enough about the possible cause here to proceed on my own.
FWIW, libobjectal-ios.a has been removed and re-added to the project repeatedly, to no avail.

Comment: try building the objectal lib alone. Check its source code for any uses of the isnan function, perhaps it can be replaced with an alternative check (isnan tests for "not a number"). Upgrading the objectal code should be doable in isolation without causing too much trouble. In general you will have a problem with cocos2d v2 because it does not compile (without bugs) to 64 bit/armv7s but Apple now requires the armv7s code in all apps.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - darn, i was planning to post to app store in 1 week, with 2.1, 32 bits only. I thought the new rule was for february. Am i wrong and facing another forklift upgrade to 3.x ?

Comment: not sure actually, it's something I picked up somewhere, it's possible that this new rule isn't yet in effect but was merely announced to be in effect at a (not so far) future date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LearnCocos2D' (Steffen's) response, I figured out how to fix this:

-Go into *Kobold2D-Libraries >> ObjectAL >> ObjectAL >> Actions >> OALAudioActions.m*

-In the source code of OALAudioAuctions.m, replace the 3 occurrences of "isnan" with "thisisnan"
(There are 3 occurrences, OALGainAction, OALPitchAction and OALPanAction, in prepareWithTarget respectively)

-Then insert the following block at the top after Line 32:

```
#pragma mark x64 compatibility
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define thisisnan(x)                                                  \
( x != x ? true : false)
#else
#define thisisnan(x)                                                  \
(isnan(x))
#endif
```